# Python Swap two digits in a number?

Tags: python, performance, swap

What is the fastest way to swap two digits in a number in Python?  I am given the numbers as strings, so it'd be nice if I could have something as fast as

```
string[j] = string[j] ^ string[j+1] 
string[j+1] = string[j] ^ string[j+1]
string[j] = string[j] ^ string[j+1]
```

Everything I've seen has been much more expensive than it would be in C, and involves making a list and then converting the list back or some variant thereof.

Comment: What digits are to be swapped?

Comment: You can't avoid a conversion from and to a mutable type here. You might try using the [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module, but I can't vouch it will be faster.

Comment: Do you know that i < j ?

Comment: came here to look for the cool mathsy solution, disappointed to see your 'number' is actually just a string  :(

Comment: @millimoose: It's possible to avoid conversion to a mutable type if the swap doesn't have to be done in-place.

Comment: @martineau You can't do an in-place swap of elements in an immutable type *at all*, so the result value will invariably be a different object than the input value. What you can do is minimise the amount of copying parts of the input into various garbage objects, whether in local variables or in a list or wherever. (This isn't the same as "conversion to a mutable type", so I admit that statement was incorrect.)

Comment: @martineau bah, maybe I read an answer instead of the question. Oops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is faster than you might think, at least faster than Jon Clements' current answer in my timing test:

```
i, j = (i, j) if i < j else (j, i) # make sure i < j
s = s[:i] + s[j] + s[i+1:j] + s[i] + s[j+1:]
```

Here's my test bed should you want to compare any other answers you get:

```
import timeit
import types

N = 10000
R = 3
SUFFIX = '_test'
SUFFIX_LEN = len(SUFFIX)

def setup():
    import random
    global s, i, j
    s = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    i = random.randrange(len(s))
    while True:
        j = random.randrange(len(s))
        if i != j: break

def swapchars_martineau(s, i, j):
    i, j = (i, j) if i < j else (j, i) # make sure i < j
    return s[:i] + s[j] + s[i+1:j] + s[i] + s[j+1:]

def swapchars_martineau_test():
    global s, i, j
    swapchars_martineau(s, i, j)

def swapchars_clements(text, fst, snd):
    ba = bytearray(text)
    ba[fst], ba[snd] = ba[snd], ba[fst]
    return str(ba)

def swapchars_clements_test():
    global s, i, j
    swapchars_clements(s, i, j)

# find all the functions named *SUFFIX in the global namespace
funcs = tuple(value for id,value in globals().items()
            if id.endswith(SUFFIX) and type(value) is types.FunctionType)

# run the timing tests and collect results
timings = [(f.func_name[:-SUFFIX_LEN],
            min(timeit.repeat(f, setup=setup, repeat=R, number=N))
           ) for f in funcs]
timings.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])  # sort by speed
fastest = timings[0][1]  # time fastest one took to run
longest = max(len(t[0]) for t in timings) # len of longest func name (w/o suffix)

print 'fastest to slowest *_test() function timings:\n' \
      ' {:,d} chars, {:,d} timeit calls, best of {:d}\n'.format(len(s), N, R)

def times_slower(speed, fastest):
    return speed/fastest - 1.0

for i in timings:
    print "{0:>{width}}{suffix}() : {1:.4f} ({2:.2f} times slower)".format(
                i[0], i[1], times_slower(i[1], fastest), width=longest, suffix=SUFFIX)
```

**Addendum:**

For the special case of swapping digit characters in a positive decimal number given as a string, the following also works and is a tiny bit faster than the general version at the top of my answer.

The somewhat involved conversion back to a string at the end with the `format()` method is to deal with cases where a zero got moved to the front of the string. I present it mainly as a curiosity, since it's fairly incomprehensible unless you grasp what it does mathematically. It also doesn't handle negative numbers.

```
n = int(s)
len_s = len(s)
ord_0 = ord('0')
di = ord(s[i])-ord_0
dj = ord(s[j])-ord_0
pi = 10**(len_s-(i+1))
pj = 10**(len_s-(j+1))
s = '{:0{width}d}'.format(n + (dj-di)*pi + (di-dj)*pj, width=len_s)
```

Comment: This could well be what the OP is after, since they're looking to hash the result later.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be of a mutable type of some sort, the best I can think of is (can't make any claims as to performance though):

```
def swapchar(text, fst, snd):
    ba = bytearray(text)
    ba[fst], ba[snd] = ba[snd], ba[fst]
    return ba

>>> swapchar('thequickbrownfox', 3, 7)
bytearray(b'thekuicqbrownfox')
```

You can still utilise the result as a `str`/`list` - or explicitly convert it to a `str` if needs be.

Comment: bytearray(b'thekuicqbrownfox') 

Is there a fast way to go from bytearray to string?

Comment: @EnderX Thanks for correction - the original code I had, had `return str(ba)` in it... That'll be the fastest method of getting a real `str`  type back that I know of, but for most purposes, you can treat the `bytearray` as a `str`

Comment: Okay, thanks, I need it as a str because I have to hash it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
    >>> int1 = 2
    >>> int2 = 3
    >>> eval(str(int1)+str(int2))
    23
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already accepted an answer, so I won't bother coding it in Python, but here's how you could do it in JavaScript which also has immutable strings:

```
function swapchar(string, j)
{
    return string.replace(RegExp("(.{" + j + "})(.)(.)"), "$1$3$2");
}
```

Obviously if `j` isn't in an appropriate range then it just returns the original string.

Answer (score 0):

Given an integer `n` and two (zero-started) indexes `i` and `j` of digits to swap, this can be done using powers of ten to locate the digits, division and modulo operations to extract them, and subtraction and addition to perform the swap.

```
def swapDigits(n, i, j):
    # These powers of 10 encode the locations i and j in n.
    power_i = 10 ** i
    power_j = 10 ** j

    # Retrieve digits [i] and [j] from n.
    digit_i = (n // power_i) % 10
    digit_j = (n // power_j) % 10

    # Remove digits [i] and [j] from n. 
    n -= digit_i * power_i
    n -= digit_j * power_j

    # Insert digit [i] in position [j] and vice versa.
    n += digit_i * power_j
    n += digit_j * power_i

    return n
```

For example:

```
>>> swapDigits(9876543210, 4, 0)
9876503214
>>> swapDigits(9876543210, 7, 2)
9826543710
```